# Reuse CGRects don't work

Tags: ios, xcode4, cgrect

I have an strange behavior on reusing CGrects in ipod touch 2G, but not in 3G 4G.
When I run the app from XCode4 with the device plugged it works just fine, but when I archive the app and upload it via itunes or through web server, comes the weird behavior.
If I go to edit scheme, select Archive and choose Build configuration: Debug, upload the app through web server, it works fine.

my code is like this

```
//this code works perfect
CGRect pos = self.toolBar.frame;
pos.origin.y = 0;
self.toolBar.frame = pos;

//this code fails, to fix it I need to create a new CGRect (CGRect pos2)
//or assign an CGRectMake to pos
pos = self.picker.frame;
pos.origin.y = self.toolBar.frame.size.height;
self.picker.frame = pos;
```

What is causing this problems. How can I compare those builds configurations (debug - release)

Edited

Comment: What's the error? What do you expect? Also, you're missing a semicolon...

Comment: Is it possible that `self.picker == nil`? That would cause weirdness.

Comment: I'm guessing you made a typo when using `por.picker.frame` instead of `pos.origin.y`. Also, as mentioned before, you're missing a semicolon.

Comment: @benzado good suggestion (+1) -- in more detail, that 'weirdness' is defined as zeroed memory. so it would perhaps be more precisely worded as "that could cause *unexpected results*".

Comment: Ok thank you CSmith, changin the compiler solves this issue.

Comment: And H2CO3 and timjver, there was typo from my part. self.picker == nil is used until dealloc or viewDidUnload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between running from XCode vs. archive is DEBUG vs. RELEASE builds, and in particular compiler optimization which is enabled in your release build.

You're likely seeing an LLVM compiler optimization bug related to armv6 processor, I had something very similar happen to me.  Try switching from LLVM to GCC compiler.  Does this resolve your issue?

Further, if you upgrade to XCode 4.5, you'll find that ARMV6 has been deprecated, so you can also choose to drop support for these old devices and be lockstep with Apple.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't leave the old devices 'cause this app is an enterprise development, i wish to leave them, but not depends on me